# How to pretty print more than one dictionary entry per line?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, pretty-print

I have a dictionary with many entries:

```
d = dict([(i, 'Data') for i in range(100)])
```

If I try to pretty print this data

```
pp = PrettyPrinter(indent=4, width=999)
pp.pprint(d)
```

it only prints one entry per line:

```
{   0: 'Data',
    1: 'Data',
    ...
    99: 'Data'}
```

However, I want it to print as many entries per line as it can fit within the limit of *width*.

Something like this:

```
{   0: 'Data', 1: 'Data', 2: 'Data',
    3: 'Data', 4: 'Data', 5: 'Data',
    ...
    99: 'Data'}
```

How can I achieve this result with an already exising package?

Comment: Please research pretty-printing, print formatting, and related topics.  One simple way would be to `join` all of the outputs into a single string, and then break it every line, finding the first comma-space pair to the left of position `width`.

Comment: Do you mind if you don't use pprint or you must use it, because with a for loop I beleive it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @Prune I'm not stupid! I can easily cook up some code that crates the string I want. pprint and similar packages exist for a reason. I want a simple and quick way that I can use in any situation, without having to format strings myself every time I just want to pretty print something. I edited my question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question since it does not use the pretty print or other existing library. It also does not account for edge cases such as a new line in keys or values, or nested/non-string types.

```
d = dict([(i, 'Data') for i in range(20)])


def print_dict(d, col_width=80, sep=','):
    if not len(d):
        print('{}')
        return
    def get_str(k, v):
        return '%s: %s' % (k, v)


    print('{', end='')
    items = iter(d.items())
    
    entry = get_str(*next(items))
    used_width = len(entry)
    print(entry, end='')

    for k, v in items:
        entry = get_str(k, v)
        
        # if the current entry's string rep will cause an overflow, and the current line
        # isn't blank, then go to the next line
        new_line = used_width + len(entry) > col_width and used_width > 0
        if new_line:
            print(f'{sep}\n', end='')
            used_width = 0
        
        print((f'{sep} ' if not new_line else '') + get_str(k, v), end='')
        used_width += len(entry)

    print('}')

print_dict(d)
```

It simply puts as many items in one line as it can without overflowing, but putting at least one item in each line.

```
{0: Data, 1: Data, 2: Data, 3: Data, 4: Data, 5: Data, 6: Data, 7: Data, 8: Data, 9: Data, 10: Data,
11: Data, 12: Data, 13: Data, 14: Data, 15: Data, 16: Data, 17: Data, 18: Data, 19: Data}
```